# Generic class of generic class in Java

Tags: java, generics

I had a class hierarchy setup like so:

```
public abstract class GameController
public abstract class Game
```

I wanted to use a generic GameController class so it takes specific Game subclasses, so I changed it to:

```
public abstract class GameController<GameType extends Game>
public abstract class Game
```

But then I also wanted to have a generic Game to take specific player subclasses, so I changed it to:

```
public abstract class GameController<GameType extends Game<PlayerType>, PlayerType extends Player>
public abstract class Game<PlayerType extends Player>
```

Is there a better way to lay this out so I don't have to declare PlayerType twice (in both the GameController subclass and the Game subclass)?

**Edit**:

GameController is a network class, it receives post and get requests, and translates them into something closer to what a game needs, then a subclass, say MyGameController, further translates the byte[] that was posted into a method call for a specific game class, say MyGame.  Code sample:

GameController:

```
public abstract class GameController<GameType extends Game<PlayerType>, PlayerType extends Player> {
    private Hashtable<String, GameType> games;
    public MultiplayerMain() {
        super();
        games = new Hashtable<String, GameType>();
    }
    protected abstract GameType createGame(InputStream in, String gameId);
    protected abstract PlayerType createPlayer(InputStream in, GameType game, String playerId);
    protected abstract byte[] gameAction(InputStream in, GameType game, PlayerType player);

    //Other stuff that calls createGame, createPlayer, and gameAction
}
```

Game:

```
public abstract class Game<PlayerType extends Player> {
    private Hashtable <String, PlayerType> players = new Hashtable<String, PlayerType>();
    public final String gameId;
    public Game (String id) {
        gameId = id;
    }
    public abstract byte[] getGameState();
    public abstract byte[] getGameState(PlayerType player);
    final PlayerType getPlayer(String userId) {
        return players.get(userId);
    }
    final void addPlayer(PlayerType player) {
        players.put(player.userId,player);
        playerAdded(player);
    }
    final void removePlayer(PlayerType player) {
        players.remove(player);
        playerRemoved(player);
    }
    protected void playerAdded(PlayerType player) {}
    protected void playerRemoved(PlayerType player) {}
}
```

MyGameController:

```
public class MyGameController extends GameController<MyGame,MyPlaer> {
    protected MyGame createGame(InputStream in, String gameId) {
        byte[] data = getInitializationData(in);
        return new MyGame(gameId,data);
    }

    protected byte[] gameAction(InputStream in, MyGame game, Player player) {
        byte[] data = getData(in);
        MyGame.methodSpecificToMyGameClassBasedOnInputStream(data);
        return game.getGameState(player);
    }

    protected Player createPlayer(InputStream in, MyGame game, String playerId) {
        byte[] otherData = getOtherData(in,game)
        return new MyPlayer(playerId,otherData);
    }
}
```

MyGame:

```
public class MyGame extends Game<MyPlayer> {

    public MyGame(String id) {
        //...
    }

    public byte[] getGameState() {
        //...
    }

    public byte[] getGameState(Player user) {
        //...
    }

    public void methodSpecificToMyGameClassBasedOnInputStream(byte[] data) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need generics for this? Instead, can you inject `Player` into `Game` and `Game` into `GameController`?

```
public class Game {
    private final PlayerType playerType;

    public Game(PlayerType playerType) {...}

}

public class GameController {
    private final Game game;

    public GameController(Game game) {...}
}
```

Comment: Well, GameController has a collection of games created with an abstract method "CreateGame" which returns a GameType object.  Subclasses then extend GameController<MyGameType> so that references to games don't have to be cast to their specific type before doing something to them

Comment: This smells.  Can you add edit your post to provide a little more code to explain what is happening?

Comment: Code sample posted.  And I still want to know the answer to my question, even if this isn't the route I go

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you need to define PlayerType in you game controller. You can probably just do the following:

```
public abstract class GameController<GameType extends Game<?>>
public abstract class Game<PlayerType extends Player>
```

gameController.getPlayer() could only return a Player, but you could still use gameController.getGame().getPlayer() which would return a PlayerType.

Edit: Based on the method signatures you have provided, no, I don't see a way to declare the generic types without declaring PlayerType twice.

I agree with the others who say your model is too coupled. It feels like gameAction shouldn't care what type of Game or Player it takes.

Comment: Except there are methods in GameController that pass in PlayerType objects, like gameAction, where the subclass then knows that the object passed in is the right type of Player subclass and doesn't have to worry about casting it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're really tightly coupling the definition of GameController to the inheritance hierarchy of Game and GameType; similarly with Game to Player and PlayerType.  I would encourage you to couple that relationship significantly more loosely; composition, as other posters are suggesting, is almost certainly the right way to go here, since you're describing as "has-a" relationship.

Comment: It looks fine to me.  GameType isn't some class, it's just the template parameter used in GameController to reference any subclass of Game, and same with PlayerType.  It just means that any subclass of GameController has a collection of some subclass of Game objects, each having some subclass of Player objects, and the subclasses can then use specific Classes and not worry about casting.